# Stirling, asymptote of $n^2+n-1\choose n$

Tags: combinatorics, limits, asymptotics, stirling-numbers

I need to find the asymptote of $n^2+n-1\choose n$. any idea? I used the Stirling formula for $n!$ but I found an unexpected final answer.

Comment: What unexpected answer? Why it is unexpected?

Comment: It's just a matter of using Stirling formula, as you did. Tell us what you found.

Comment: I was expecting e^p(n)*n^q(n) while p and q are polynomials in n. But I don't get close to it

Comment: I did use stirling formula but I found something which I don't trust. I was wondering what others may arrived to

Answer (score 1):

Let's try

Using $\log(n!) = n  \log(n) -n + O(\log(n))$ I get: $$ \log {n^2+n-1\choose n}  
= (n^2 +n-1) \log(n^2+n-1) - (n^2 +n-1)  - n  \log(n) +  n \\- (n^2-1)\log(n^2-1) + n^2 -1+ O(\log(n^2))=\\=
(n^2 -1) \log(\frac{n^2 +n-1}{n^2 -1}) + n\log(\frac{n^2 +n-1}{n}) + O(\log(n^2))$$

But

$$\log(\frac{n^2 +n-1}{n^2 -1})= \frac{1}{n} + O(n^{-2})$$

$$\log(\frac{n^2 +n-1}{n})=\log(n)+O(1)$$

So $$ \log {n^2+n-1\choose n}  \approx n + n \log(n)$$

Comment: Great!! Tnx so much leonbloy for your help:)